# Hot to get stored procedure SQL text?

Tags: stored-procedures, advantage-database-server, data-dictionary

Is there any way to retrieve (and update) the actual stored procedure SQL text from a data dictionary?

A sample use case for this would be to write a replacement tool for the Advantage Data Architect. However at the moment I really need this to workaround a bug in ADS 9.1.

I imagine there must be something like:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_GetStoredProcedureProperty('PROCNAME', 'SQLTEXT');
```

I found a system procedure called `sp_ModifyProcedureProperty` that can be used to modify some parts of a SP:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_modifyprocedureproperty.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system table in the dictionary called `system.storedprocedures` which has a field named `SQL_Script` that does what I need.

Example:

```
SELECT SQL_Script FROM system.storedprocedures WHERE Name = 'PROCNAME';
```

Comment: Hi, How to sort this error on this one:  
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'system.storedprocedures'.

Comment: Your error message seems to be coming from Microsoft SQL Server, this question was about Advantage Database Server. You can achieve something similar with the `OBJECT_DEFINITION` and `OBJECT_ID` functions in SQL Server.